# How to find duplicate column values in pyspark datafarme

Tags: pyspark, duplicates, find

I am trying to find the duplicate column value from dataframe in pyspark.

for example, I have a dataframe with single column 'A' with values like below:

```
==
A
==
1
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

I am expecting output like below(only duplicate values I need)

```
==
A
==
1
5
```

Comment: you can probably accept a solution or comment if there are some problems

Answer (score 7):

same answer as @Yuva but using the built-in functions :

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,),(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,),(5,),(5,)],('A',))

df.groupBy("A").count().where("count > 1").drop("count").show()

+---+
|  A|
+---+
|  5|
|  1|
+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this, and see if this helps?

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,),(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,),(5,),(5,)],('A',))
df.createOrReplaceTempView(df_tbl)
spark.sql("select A, count(*) as COUNT from df_tbl group by a having COUNT > 1").show()

+---+-----+
|  A|COUNT|
+---+-----+
|  5|2    |
|  1|2    |
+---+-----+
```